# Is iOS4.0 a requirement for app store submission?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is iOS4.0 compatibility required for all app-store submissions now?

To my understanding, your application is required to run on iOS4.0 now. It can -also- be compatible for iOS3.x, but there is no way to submit an application and have it run for 3.x only.

(Note: When I say 3.x, I mean <3.2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your app will be rejected if it breaks on iOS 4.

Comment: @mmmilo - I would assume that it would be common sense to think that your application would be rejected if it breaks on the currently shipping OS.